# Inner product in module theory

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, inner-products, projective-module

Consider an $R$-module $M$, for a $R$ a commutative ring with identity.

Of course one could define the notion of inner nondegenerate* symmetric product $(-,-)$ in the same fashion of vector spaces.

> - Is this something that has been found of some interest in mathematics?
> - Is it true, for example, that the natural map $M\to \text{Hom}(M,R)$ sending $m\mapsto (m,-)$ is an isomorphism when $M$ is projective (or under other conditions)? Note that it is at least injective by nondegeneracy.

Thank you in advance.

*i.e. $\forall m\in M\ \exists n\in M$ s.t. $(m,n)\neq 0$.

Comment: The map is an isomorphism for finitely generated projective modules.

Comment: The non-degeneracy you define is in general too weak for rings. A better and frequently used notion would be for all $m\in M$ there exists $n\in M$ such that $(m,n)=1$. Then, the second bullet point above is true for finitely generated projective modules.

Comment: @Mohan do you have a proof or a reference for such a claim? Do you know some additional hypotheses that would imply the isomorphism also for non finitely generated modules?

Comment: My claim is fairly easy to prove, by localizing. I do not know how this could be true for infinitely generated modules, since it fails even for fields.

Comment: This is why I spoke about *additional hypotheses*.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti No reasonable hypothesis can be put other than finite generation; that is what I meant by using the field case.